# Error 500 when trying to send file from remote server (python code) to an SFTP server

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, sftp, paramiko

I have a Flask API in a Docker container where I do the following :

```
from flask import Flask, request
import os
import json
import paramiko
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Service up in K8S!"

@app.route("/get", methods=['GET'])
def get_ano():
    print("Test liveness")
    return "Pod is alive !"

@app.route("/run", methods=['POST'])
def run_dump_generation():
    rules_str = request.headers.get('database')
    print(rules_str)

    postgres_bin = r"/usr/bin/"
    dump_file = "database_dump.sql"

    os.environ['PGPASSWORD'] = 'XXXXX'

    print('Before dump generation')

    with open(dump_file, "w") as f:
            result = subprocess.call([
                    os.path.join(postgres_bin, "pg_dump"), 
                    "-Fp", 
                    "-d", 
                    "XX", 
                    "-U", 
                    "XX", 
                    "-h", 
                    "XX", 
                    "-p", 
                    "XX"
                    ],
                    stdout=f
                    )
    
    print('After dump generation')

    transport = paramiko.Transport(("X", X))
    transport.connect(username="X", password="X")
    sftp = transport.open_sftp_client()
    remote_file = '/data/database_dump.sql'
    sftp.put('database_dump.sql', remote_file)

    print("SFTP object", sftp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

When I run the app in Kubernetes with Post request I have the error : `"POST /run HTTP/1.1" 500`

Here are the requirements.txt:

```
Flask==2.0.1
paramiko==3.0.0
```

The error comes from `transport = paramiko.Transport(("X", X))`. The same code works locally. I don't understand why I have this error when I am on Kubernetes. But in the logs no print are displaying, I guess it is because I have error 500. I guess it is not possible with this code to send file from this container to the SFTP server (has OpenSSH).

What can I do ?

---- UPDATE ----

I think I have found the problem. In a Flask pod (VM) I try to send file from this pod to SFTP server. So I have to modify the following code to "allow" this type of send. This an SFTP server with OpenSSH.

Here is the code where to modify :

```
transport = paramiko.Transport(("X", X))
transport.connect(username="X", password="X")
sftp = transport.open_sftp_client()
remote_file = '/data/database_dump.sql'
sftp.put('database_dump.sql', remote_file)

print("SFTP object", sftp)
```

SFTP server (with OpenSSH) is alpine and Flask code is in Alpine container too.

UPDATE BELOW, I tried the following :

```
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
session = ssh.connect(hostname="X", port=X, username='X', password="X")
print(ssh)
```

But I have the following error :

```
  File "c:/Users/X/dump_generator_api/t.py", line 32, in <module>
    session = ssh.connect(hostname="X", port=X, username='X', password="X")
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 449, in connect
    self._auth(
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 780, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 767, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1567, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\auth_handler.py", line 259, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Post Paramiko logs from both environments.

Comment: I do not see any logs.